# How can I save my JBOD "files" when moving from Windows Home Server to Windows Server Essentials 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-home-server, jbod, storage-spaces

I had a Windows Home Server (not 2011) that finally up and died on me.  Instead of going through the effort of re-installing an outdated OS, I decided to install Windows Server Essentials 2012, since that's supposed to be the new offering in this area.

I had 2 500GB drives & 1 320GB drive in my old server configured as JBOD.  Several folders were flagged to be redundant.

Everything with the install went great & I'm liking the new server.  However when I plug in my  drives from my old server, I have several small drives with folders in them, which if I check the properties, it's showing 400GB+ on a 120GB partition (so I'm assuming this a pointer of some sort).  Then a 490GB partition that appears to be completely empty.

So, how can I get my data "back" so that it doesn't look like I have an empty 500GB drive out there & things look normal again?

Sorry for being so long winded.

Comment: Restore from backup?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm a horrible home sysadmin & my most recent backup is a couple months old.  

I can still access all of my files via the "share folders" it's just odd.  I may just throw a new HD in there, copy everything off & reformat the existing drives.  I was just hoping someone had an "easy way" for me to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the solution if you need to rebuild the server is fairly straight forward:

1. Build up the new box & get it all settled.
2. Re-attach the old drive(s).
3. On the "data" drives, set windows explorer to show hidden files/folders.
4. Double-click the "DE" folder that was previously hidden.
5. Double-click the "shares" folder.
6. In here you should see any "folders" that were stored on this drive.
7. Some of these folders will unfortunately be empty
8. Any files here should be copied onto a new/fresh drive.